# Is there any file size limitation on download file from Database on spring mvc?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc.
I want to download file from database.
and I want to know any limitation is exsit when download file in spring mvc.
Sorry, I am beginner in spring mvc.
I found upload file size config in web.xml,**max-file-size**
But , I can not find any limitation for dowanload file.
I mean how many file size(1G or 2G or ..) can download?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just try it ?

Comment: Yeah. I am finding limiation size for download, Still not found yet. I think for download size limitation can not config and can be download a large of file size depending on pc of memory and performance. If you know something about download limitation . Please teach me. thanks. @Marged